# katex to load as webpack externals

Tags: webpack, katex

I'm trying to get Katex in marked editor,
https://github.com/markedjs/marked/issues/1538
took the code from the above link, works great!

```
const marked = require('marked');
const katex = require('katex');  // external

const renderer = new marked.Renderer();

function mathsExpression(expr) {
  if (expr.match(/^\$\$[\s\S]*\$\$$/)) {
    expr = expr.substr(2, expr.length - 4);
    return katex.renderToString(expr, { displayMode: true });
  } else if (expr.match(/^\$[\s\S]*\$$/)) {
    expr = expr.substr(1, expr.length - 2);
    return katex.renderToString(expr, { isplayMode: false });
  }
}
```

but I would like to load katex as separate module, so I'm trying to use externals from webpack: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

```
output: {
      path: PATH(isDev),
      filename: "bundle.js",
      library: "BUNDLE",
      libraryExport: "default",
      libraryTarget: "umd",
      globalObject: "this",
    },
externals: {
      katex: {
        root: "katex",
        commonjs2: "katex",
        commonjs: "katex",
        amd: "katex",
      },
    },
```

but katex in the above code is coming out as undefined, but that is available outside in the HTML file. As I've added katex js file

```
<script
        src="../katex/katex.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-g7c+Jr9ZivxKLnZTDUhnkOnsh30B4H0rpLUpJ4jAIKs4fnJI+sEnkvrMWph2EDg4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```

I think I'm missing something here ... could you please help me out here. Thanks

Comment: can you please post the generated `const katex = require('katex');  // external` that webpack creates please? the bundle without the mapping? at least the generated ____webpack__require____ command of katex?

Comment: Also, is the script tag for ../katex/katex.min.js in the html is defined before the script tag of the generated main chunk entry point?
Otherwise `window.katex` maybe generated after the `require('katex')` is been run

Comment: var katex = __webpack_require__(/*! katex */ \"katex\"); // external, and  yes, katex.min is placed in the head .. and main entry point is at the end of body!

Comment: what version of katex are your running? in the latest one the path for `katex.min.js` is: `node_modules\katex\dist\katex.min.js`

Comment: version: "0.12.0" .. I've downloaded it to local and using ../katex/katex.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
externals: {
   katex: "katex"
},
```

notice the **"** katex **"**

please?

---

I created a local demo of it with files:

-webpack.config.js

-src

--index.js

-dist

--index.html

**Files:**

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  externals: {
      katex: "katex"
  }
};
```

src/index.js

```
var katex = require("katex");

export function foo() {
    console.log(katex);
}

foo();
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>External Demo</title>
    <script
        src="../node_modules/katex/dist/katex.min.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Result in console:
`{version: "0.12.0", render: ƒ, renderToString: ƒ, ParseError: ƒ, __parse: ƒ, …}`
And then I can use katex inside `foo` function.

Comment: yes, I tried that .. before trying root, common, amd ...

Comment: is katex available from window in the console?

Comment: no luck, tried "window.katex": "katex" & "katex": "window.katex",

Comment: In order to see that the `external` configuration actually caught by webpack, you should see the string `external "katex"` in the main.js or your first chunk or webpack bootstrap chunk.  Inside it you should see `eval("module.exports = katex;")`

Comment: eval("module.exports = __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_katex__;\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack://BREM/external_%22katex%22?"); I've this.

Comment: Maybe it depends which webpack version are you running, I have this:```/***/ "katex":
/*!************************!*\
  !*** external "katex" ***!
  \************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

eval("module.exports = katex;\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///external_%22katex%22?");

/***/ })```

Comment: I think both are same ... I've this output: {
      path: PATH(isDev),
      filename: "brem.js",
      library: "BREM",
      libraryExport: "default",
      libraryTarget: "umd",
      globalObject: "this",
    },

Comment: can the katex.js be loaded from cdn or other folder ... or only from node_modules?

Comment: it can be loaded from anywhere

Comment: what webpack version are you running? 4.43?

Comment: webpack: 4.42.1

Comment: looks like the culprit is libraryExport: "default",

Comment: I'm running 4.43, maybe that's what differ between us, cause I defined the same output configuration as you did now and it works.